# Changes made to html / css / js (stored on NTFS partition) are lost

Tags: files, ntfs, system, html

I edit web pages (saved on NTFS partition) using Komodo Edit. As long as I usu Ubuntu (12.04) everything seems to be fine (changes appear to be saved), but after rebooting / switching to windows 8 all changes in html / css / js files are lost. Same thing goes with png / jpg images edited with Gimp.

I have also noticed some worrying changes in random files (parts of some are put in different ones) which makes me wonder if the whole issue is somehow connected with NTFS file system handling.

On the other hand I have no problem with downloading to or creating new files on the NTFS partition while using Ubuntu.

I will appreciate any feedback on this matter.

Answer (score 0):

You have to disable windows fast reboot. Fast reboot prevents you from saving yoru changes when you dual boot.

[image]

See http://www.typicaltips.com/2013/02/disable-fast-startup-in-windows-8.html